# Sorting issue with dicts and lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict that looks like this:

```
dict1 = {'lion': ['gazelle'], 'jackal': ['grass', 'zebra', 'gazelle'], 'gazelle': ['grass', 'acacia leaves'], 'zebra': ['grass']}
```

and I have this code here:

```
for x,y in sorted(dict1.items()):
    print(x,":",sep="",end=" ")
    print(', '.join(y))
```

and the code outputs this:

```
gazelle: grass, acacia leaves
jackal: grass, zebra, gazelle
lion: gazelle
zebra: grass
```

as you can see, the keys are sorted but not the values. I would like to also sort the values in alphabetical order but I am not sure how to achieve that?

what I want is:

```
gazelle: acacia leaves, grass
jackal: gazelle, grass, zebra
lion: gazelle
zebra: grass
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `sorted` with the values in `y`:

```
for x,y in sorted(dict1.items()):
    print(x,":",sep="",end=" ")
    print(', '.join(sorted(y)))
```